# (Continuous) speech-recognition of limited words in the web-browser

Tags: web, speech-recognition

Is there a solution for speech recognition which

- Only has a few words (2 is enough, 10 would be cool. 100 is awesome. More isn't needed)
- Runs on mobile browsers too (Is it possible to use flash (rather than java) for this?)
- Can be installed on your own server. Preferably with PHP+MySQL (if server-side code is required)

I tried searching but I only found actual transcription services (like the Google Voice Search for Android).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Speech recognition with Flash or Silverlight](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748134/speech-recognition-with-flash-or-silverlight)

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with the outcome?

Comment: Thank you Mat.
I want to control audio playback (play / pause) of an MP3-file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of such a solution is [touchless-timer](https://github.com/Kaljurand/touchless-timer), which is based on [pocketsphinx.js](https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js) (also mentioned in Nikolay Shmyrev's post). To answer your bullet points:

- it supports a simple alarm clock grammar with ~60 words (phrases like "wake me up in five minutes");
- I've managed to run it in Chrome Beta 32.0.1700.99 Android 4.1.2 (on Samsung Galaxy S2), it requires a modern Javascript engine, but does not require Flash;
- it does not require a server, because speech recognition is done offline in Javascript, and all the required files can be cached using ApplicationCache.

For this application, the grammar was written in [Grammatical Framework](http://www.grammaticalframework.org/) and automatically converted to the finite state model and dictionary required by pocketsphinx.js. For a simple "MP3 play/pause" grammar you can easily write the FSA directly.

The English acoustic models in this app are not very good, i.e. they might get confused by the MP3 playing in the background. You might be able to improve on that by training better models. However, better models might be larger (e.g. > 20 MB in Javascript) and not fit into memory anymore or just make the app run/load very slowly.

Screenshot of the app running on mobile:

[image: Screenshot of Timer running on a smartphone]

Answer (score 1):

These days you don't even need a server to run speech recognition, you only need a browser which supports Web Audio API (both recent firefox and chrome support it). CMUSphinx now can be executed in javascript in your browser.

For more details see

https://github.com/syl22-00/pocketsphinx.js

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/2013/06/voice-enable-your-website-with-cmusphinx/

Comment: This didn't work for me on Xubuntu with Firefox or Chromium. In Chromium Flash wasn't responding to clicking to allow permission. In Firefox that worked but nothing appeared to happen in automatic or manual mode.

Comment: Hey, a lot has been changed in last two years. I've updated the answer, please try a new client-side technology, it should work without flash.

Comment: I wouldn't call that usable either. I tried it and almost it worked the first time, but recognised the number wrong, (as well as being slow), after that, even after refreshing, I couldn't get it to do anything.I wouldn't delete the old solution: at least that had a shot at possibly working in Firefox.